# Are questions not related to an app's web UI off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions like this on topic or no?

**"How do I do [fill in the blank] with App Y for my mobile device?"**

**"How do I do [fill in the blank] with App Y's desktop client?"**

Where App Y is a well established web app that normally would be on topic if you were using the web UI (Facebook, Twitter, etc).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I fear a situation where the communities on the respective sites will each claim the question is off-topic and punt it to the other.

For instance, a question about the Android Facebook client is excluded from web apps because it's about an Android app, while it is also excluded from the Android SE site because it's just a client for a web app.

All that will do is serve to exclude and annoy the people who are honestly looking for help and for whom these sites are ostensibly created.

I think a little flexibility and allowance for overlap is needed. Yes, off-topic questions are annoying and diffuse focus, but rigid "no, you need to go here" messages for borderline cases smack all-too-much of government bureaucracy where each department passes the buck to the next.

Comment: I agree. +1 We need to allow SOME overlap.

Comment: I agree too, well put.

Answer (score 2):

I think they are **off topic**.

They're not really about the web application in question, but about native applications.

These questions are better fit on their respective SE sites:

- If it's about a destop application, this would be Super User,
- smartphone applications go to SlideToAsk.com or ForceClose.com or to an alternate SE 2.0 site which is yet to be created.

Comment: I don't know. I mean, we have to allow SOME overlap. Are webapps then defined as only things you access with a browser? What if I go to facebook.com on my iPhone mobile safari? That's on-topic, but using the same device to access the same web service using the official app is off-topic?

Comment: @Mike: That's exactly what I mean, yes. If we close questions about web apps on Super User as off topic, then we should close questions about desktop apps or any device specific apps as off topic here as well.

Answer (score 1):

I thing questions about “add on” mobile and PC apps are OK provided the application is there to make the use of the web app easier and the **web applications is useful without the “add on” application**.

So a question about photo uploading with a Facebook mobile app is ok, but a question about formatting in Microsoft Word is not OK even if the word documented is being stored on SharePoint.

If the “add on” application can be used (or is often used) by someone that does not use the web application, I think the questions will most likely be off topic.